# PHP won't show user_temp variable

Tags: php, json, variables

I have a simple app for showing current weather.
`

```
    //------------------------------------------------connect to API and get info
    $appid = "";
    $api_url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" . $user_city . "," . $user_country . "&appid=" . $appid;
    $weather_data = file_get_contents($api_url);
    $json = json_decode($weather_data, TRUE);
    //------------------------------------------------

    //------------------------------------------------ get info from API
    $user_temp = $json['main']['main.temp'];
    $user_humidity = $json['main']['humidity'];
    $user_conditions = $json['weather'][0]['main'];
    $user_wind = $json['wind']['speed'];
    $user_wind_direction = $json['wind']['deg'];
    //-----------------------------------------------

    //----------------------------------------------output
    echo "<strong> City: </strong>" . $user_city . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> json: </strong>" . $json . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Country: </strong>" . $user_country . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Humidity: </strong>" . $user_humidity . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Current Conditions: </strong>" . $user_conditions . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Wind Speed: </strong>" . $user_wind . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Wind Direction: </strong>" . $user_wind_direction . "<br />";
    echo "<strong> Current Temperature: </strong>" . $user_temp . "<br />";
};
```

?>`

It shows me City and Country, but not temp, humidity and so on.
Does someone know where can be problem?

Comment: Did you `print_r($json)` already?

Comment: `echo "<strong> json: </strong>" . $json . "<br />";` << here, you should read an **Array to string conversion at** notice, you're trying to echo an associative array (if your file_get_contents actually received anything)

Comment: `$user_city` and `$user_country` are defined previous to the code block you posted, so it's more likely they exists, rather than the `$json` content that remains mysterious if has anything on it.

Comment: provide json file also

Comment: Your `print_r` shows you this? Then there is something wrong, because `$json` should have an associative array and not a json string

Answer (score 0):

Is your AppID set correctly?

Alternatively you could use 
[OpenWeatherMap PHP API](https://github.com/cmfcmf/OpenWeatherMap-PHP-Api)

Answer (score 0):

city and country is getting because you are not taking it from json.
and to print decoded json you should use `print_r($json)`.

for eg. **json**

```
{"coord":{"lon":139,"lat":35},
"sys":{"country":"JP","sunrise":1369769524,"sunset":1369821049},
"weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04n"}],

"main":{"temp":289.5,"humidity":89,"pressure":1013,"temp_min":287.04,"temp_max":292.04},
"wind":{"speed":7.31,"deg":187.002},
"rain":{"3h":0},
"clouds":{"all":92},
"dt":1369824698,
"id":1851632,
"name":"Shuzenji",
"cod":200}
```

**php code**

```
//------------------------------------------------ get info from API
$user_temp = $json['main']['temp'];
$user_humidity = $json['main']['humidity'];
$user_conditions = $json['weather'][0]['main'];
$user_wind = $json['wind']['speed'];
$user_wind_direction = $json['wind']['deg'];
//-----------------------------------------------
```